# NullPointerException with PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, priority-queue

I encounter a problem with using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` in a custom thread pull where the poll method causes a `NullPointerException`. When using this setup

```
int POOL_SIZE = 5;
int OVERHEAD_POOL_SIZE = 10;
long LIFE_TIME = 5000;
TimeUnit LIFE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
```

with

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(POOL_SIZE, OVERHEAD_POOL_SIZE,
        LIFE_TIME, LIFE_TIME_UNIT, new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

instead of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, I *sometimes* encounter the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "pool-14-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftDownComparable(PriorityQueue.java:624)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftDown(PriorityQueue.java:614)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.poll(PriorityQueue.java:523)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Basically, I want to order `Runnable`s in the queue by a priority:

```
class MyRunnableFuture implements 
        RunnableFuture<Boolean>, Comparable<MyRunnableFuture>
```

The wired thing is: The exception is not always thrown, but if I set a breakpoint inside of `PriorityQueue.siftDownComparable`, the chance for the exception to occure is higher.

Any ideas? I found other people [having the same problem](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t388665-npe-in-priorityqueue-poll.html), but nobody really knew a solution. Do I have to synchronize the queue manually when used in a `ThreadPool`? I am using the queue, because I do not want to synchronize it. I understood the descriptions as if the queue was already synchronized internally? Thanks for any answers!

Comment: The `PriorityBlockingQueue` wraps the `PriorityQueue` in locks.  You certainly should _not_ have to do your own locking around it.

Comment: I think there is bug logged for this, read comments for the bug http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6495524

Comment: It says however: "We are skeptical about this being a bug in the libraries. It seems more likely that this is a bug in the user program. To be able to reproduce this kind of a problem, we really need a small reproducible test case using only core JDK APIs. Note that PriorityQueue is not thread-safe, and the reliability problem only occurs when using multiple threads, which again suggests that
the user program is faulty."
I am using it in the context of Jersey. If I skip the Jersey interface, the problem does however never occur. This might however be related to the latency which is less.

Comment: Any chance you are modifying your comparable `Runnable` while this is going on?  Are you changing the sort order of these on the fly?  That may not be allowed.

Comment: @Gray: No, the values used in the compare method are all `final int`s.

Comment: How are you even seeing the stack track @raphw?  You setting your own factory?  And can you edit your question and put the real values in the your `ThreadPoolExecutor` code?

Comment: The values are configurable, I use the above configuration in my test setup.

Comment: The stack trace is visible thanks to IntelliJ tracking all JVM threads.

Comment: Just a FYI, but your pool will _never_ allocate more than 5 threads.  Unfortunately the `ThreadPoolExecutor` fills the queue before it allocates more than the core threads.  Since your queue isn't bounded it will never fail the `offer()` call.

Comment: Thats interesting to know! I might want to find a work arround for that, maybe that solves my NullPointerException as well. I will keep this question updated.

Comment: What is the exact Java version you are using (as the links all point to seven year old maybe-bugs)? Did you ever try other versions?

Comment: I tried with the latest versions of Java 6 and Java 7. I found a solution to the problem the other day. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated after reading the comments below**: All troubles were caused by using `submit` instead of `execute` where in the former, all threads are wrapped in a `RunnableFuture` internally which of course do not implement the `Comparable` interface. This is why the comparison failed. I got distracted by the `NullPointerException` which is caused when a new worker thread is trying to pull the job that could not be inserted before. (The clue: The `PriorityBlockingQueue` does not insert the new job because a `ClassCastException` is thrown. At the same time, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` thinks there is a new job available and alerts the next worker. The worker pulls a nonexistant job and throws a `NullPointerException`. The `ClassCastException` got swallowed and logged deep down my application, I did not trace this carefully enough since I tried to find the reason for the `NullPointerException`.

For the sake of completeness, the submit method of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` actually does the following:

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

Thanks to you guys for help (in the comments!).

PS: Mean bug.

Comment: Well, every time you use `submit` instead of `execute` your `ThreadPoolExecutor` will queue a `RunnableFuture` not being a `MyRunnable` unless you override the executor’s factory method. But I would expect `ClassCastException`s rather than `null` values in this case.

Comment: Ok, that’s most likely the problem: the `ClassCastException`(s) occur, e.g. on insert, but they are catched and ignored at some place. But at this time, the queue has updated its `size` field already. Thus it will fail at a later time with an NPE trying to access that item which never got stored.

Comment: FML. I was not even aware that I used `submit` instead of `execute`. This did of course solve my problem. I found that some of the background threads caused a `ClassCastException` while others yielded a `NullPointerException`. Using `execute` instead of `submit` made both go away.